# how to change button text with 'Loading' after submit form and reset form after submit in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms

```js
var app = angular.module('snc', []);
app.controller('contactForm', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'php-form/form.php',
        data: $scope.user,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
      })
      .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (!data.success) {
          if ($scope.errorName = data.errors.name) {
            $(".alert-set").removeClass('alert-danger');
            $(".alert-set").removeClass('alert-success');
            $(".alert-set").fadeIn(1000);
            $(".alert-set").removeClass("hide");
            $(".alert-set").fadeOut(5000);
            $(".alert-set").addClass('alert-warning');
            $(".Message-txt").text(data.errors.name);
          } else if ($scope.errorMobile = data.errors.mobile) {
            $(".alert-set").removeClass('alert-danger');
            $(".alert-set").removeClass('alert-success');
            $(".alert-set").fadeIn(1000);
            $(".alert-set").removeClass("hide");
            $(".alert-set").fadeOut(5000);
            $(".alert-set").addClass('alert-warning');
            $(".Message-txt").text(data.errors.mobile);
          } else if (data.errors.email == 'fail') {
            $(".alert-set").removeClass('alert-danger');
            $(".alert-set").removeClass('alert-success');
            $(".alert-set").fadeIn(1000);
            $(".alert-set").removeClass("hide");
            $(".alert-set").fadeOut(5000);
            $(".alert-set").addClass('alert-warning');
            $(".Message-txt").text('Sorry, Failed to send E-mail.');
          } else {
            $(".alert-set").removeClass('alert-warning');
            $(".alert-set").removeClass('alert-success');
            $(".alert-set").fadeIn(1000);
            $(".alert-set").removeClass("hide");
            $(".alert-set").fadeOut(5000);
            $(".alert-set").addClass('alert-dnager');
            $(".Message-txt").text('somthing went wrong please try again.');
          }
        } else {
          $(".alert-set").removeClass('alert-danger');
          $(".alert-set").removeClass('alert-warning');
          $(".alert-set").fadeIn(1000);
          $(".alert-set").removeClass("hide");
          $(".alert-set").fadeOut(5000);
          $(".alert-set").addClass('alert-success');
          $(".Message-txt").text(data.message);
          this.submitForm = {};
        }
      });
  };
});
```

```html
<form name="queryForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name">Name:<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Mobile">Mobile:<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="user.mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Message">Message:</label>
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.message" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Message" rows="4"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-snc">Submit</button>
  <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-set">
    <strong class='Message-txt'></strong>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have a simple contact form it has to send query data to php page and I want to disable button and change button text after submitting form and also full form reset after submit. I tried but I always get some type of angular error. Can you help me to solve it and if you are a Angular Developer then can you please check this form and let me know if I need to change something.

Comment: please write your angularjs error also

Comment: Its failed to change submit button text after submit and reset when form submitted

Comment: As @PrashantPokhriyal said, `write your angularjs error`, don't explain what's going wrong ;-). What is, exactly, the error message returned?

Comment: Do you know that `$scope.errorName = data.errors.name` (assignation) is not the same than `$scope.errorName == data.errors.name` (comparison)?

Answer (score 1):

An assignation is not a comparison:

```
$scope.errorName = data.errors.name ;
```

… is an assignation which means: put the `data.errors.name` into the `$scope.errorName` variable.

```
$scope.errorName == data.errors.name
```

… is a comparison which means: `data.errors.name` is equal to `$scope.errorName`.

If you use an assignation instead of a comparison, the result will always be true as long as the value is true-like.

So:

```
if ( a = 1 ) { /* always true */ }

if ( a == 1 ) { /* true only if `a` is equal to 1 */

if ( a === 1 ) { /* true only if `a` is strictly equal to 1 */

if ( a = "false" ) { /* always true (a string not empty is true) */ }

if ( a == "false" ) { /* true only if `a` is equal to "false" */

if ( a === "false" ) { /* true only if `a` is strictly equal to "false" */
```

The *strictly* above means *of the same type*. For instance:

```
1 == "1"  // => true

1 === "1" // => not true. The Former is a Number, the latter is 
          //    a String.
```

Comment: OK, i change got it. but how i reset full form after submit

Comment: Help us to help you. Could you please add the `console.log(data)` to your answer so we can see what error is?

Comment: Now it's fixed and my form working good now. but i can't find any answer about change button text and reset form.

Answer (score 1):

To reset the form, you could use something like:

*(Mind: you've got two `name` ID. An ID should be UNIQ on your page).*

```js
function onSubmit()
{
  $('#submit_button').text('Loading…');
  resetForm();
}

function resetForm()
{
  for(let id of ['name','mobile','email', 'message'])
  {
    $("#"+id).val('');
    
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="queryForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Name">Name:<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Mobile">Mobile:<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="user.mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" value="some text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Message">Message:</label>
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.message" id="message" placeholder="Enter Your Message" rows="4">Some text</textarea>
  </div>
  <button id="submit_button" type="button" class="btn btn-snc" onclick="onSubmit()">RESET FORM</button>
  <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-set">
    <strong class='Message-txt'></strong>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ohh, its too easy thanks men. but what about loading button..?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful you are

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the typo like:

```
$(".alert-set").addClass('alert-dnager');
```

To avoid it, try to keep your code as clean as possible. You'll be able to avoid a lot of errors, you'll have a better understanding of your code, and other people can help you more efficiency.

Your `if error` statement could become:

```
.success(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  if ( false === data.success) {

    // Typo error avoiding: NOT plain-text USE variables
    let alertClass = '.alert-set';
    let errMessage = '' ;

    // Reduce the amount of code
    $(alertClass)
     .addClass('alert-warning')
     .removeClass('alert-success')
     .fadeIn(1000)
     .removeClass("hide")
     .fadeOut(5000)
     .removeClass('alert-danger') ;

    // Treat only what you have to treat
    // You could use a lambda function, too:
    //   let errMessage = function(val){ return ... }(actual value);

    if ( $scope.errorName == data.errors.name )
    {
      errMessage = data.errors.name ;
    } 
    else if ( $scope.errorMobile == data.errors.mobile )
    {
      errMessage = data.errors.mobile ;
    } 
    else if (data.errors.email == 'fail')
    {
      errMessage = 'Sorry, Failed to send E-mail.';
    } 
    else {
      errMessage = 'somthing went wrong please try again.' ;
    }

    // Only one action
    $(".Message-txt").text(errMessage) ;
```

Now we can work ;-).

Keep in mind that we don't want to help you if your code is not clean and if we can't understand at a first glance what's going on.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot for your suggestion, But i want to reset form after submitted . and show loading when form submitting...

Comment: i already tried this code, i'm using angular and when i use that code its showing loading before submitting form.

Comment: Sorry @DeepakSaini, I've done my best, I had to leave, now. Courage!